# JProfiler> ERROR unknown frame type in StackMapTable Exception and core dumped

Tags: jboss, jprofiler

When I start the Jprofiler v7.2.3 in instrumentation mode for my application, system crashes and throws below hs_err_pid.log and at times core dumps too

Internal Error (jvmtiRedefineClasses.cpp:2312), pid=19786, tid=52

## Error: ShouldNotReachHere()

Also I get below entry in nohup.out
JProfiler> ERROR unknown frame type in StackMapTable attributeAbort

Application details
Java version "1.6.0_23" 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)
jboss-5.1.0
sun4v sparc SUNW,T5140 sunOS

Please suggest the possible root cause and fix. Thanks

Comment: Besides JProfiler, do you have another -javaagent, -agentlib or
-agentpath parameter in your Java invocation? Please send the hs_err_pid.log file to support@ej-technologies.com

Comment: Hi Ingo, you are right. I have foglight configured for this application javaagent:/local/Quest_Software/Foglight_Agent_Manager/agents/JavaEE/5.8.2-5.8.2-20121206-1612/lib/performasure-agent.jar                           so should I disable it , please suggest . Thanks

Comment: Yes, please remove the other agent.

Comment: Thanks Ingo, removing the agent made it work.

Answer (score 0):

Summing up the comments: In this case, another agent has produced an invalid StackMapTable attribute in the class file of an instrumented class and JProfiler did not know how to deal with that.